# How to run numpy.unique counts through a Python 2.7 for loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to just dump a quick and dirty histogram of the values of pixels in a 2D matrix using numpy.unique.

When I run

```
for v, c in numpy.unique(imageStack[:, :, 19], return_counts=True):
    print("{}: {}".format(v, c))
```

I get "ValueError: too many values to unpack"

When I run

```
for v, c in zip(numpy.unique(matrix_2d, return_counts=True)):
    print("{}: {}".format(v,c))
```

I get "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"

Comment: what are you zipping? the zip call is expecting another value to unpack since you passed 2 variable, but you are only passing it one object. try taking away `zip`

Comment: @d_kennetz numpy.unique(imageStack[:, :, 19], return_counts=True) which returns (array([  0,  54,  86,  88, 120, 128, 134, 136, 138, 204, 255], dtype=uint8),
 array([10234384,    13123,    10822,     3046,      109,    11619,
           13750,     4994,     1535,    64281,  2407521]))

Comment: you need to splat into `zip`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @juanpa.arrivillaga in the comments above the answer is

```
for v, c in zip(*numpy.unique(matrix_2d, return_counts=True)):
    print("{}: {}".format(v,c))
```